# Finding The Tangent Line to $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = 1$

Tags: calculus

Hello everyone I have a function $\sqrt{x} +\sqrt{y} = 1$ and I have a tangent line to this function that cut

the axises at $A , B$.

How can I proof that $OA + OB = 1$.

$O = (0,0)$.

I tried to mark = $A = (a , 0) , B(0, b)$
and find the tangent line by A and B

and make some equations with the function but I got to nowhere.

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg That's not kind!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Why do you think so?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Just joking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M(a,b)$ be a touching point.

Thus, since $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+\frac{y'}{2\sqrt{y}}=0,$$ we obtain for the slope:
$$m=-\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$$ and the equation of the tangent:
$$y-b=-\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}(x-a)$$ or
$$y=-\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}x+b+\sqrt{ab}.$$ 
Now, for $x=0$ we get $y=b+\sqrt{ab}$ and for $y=0$ we obtain $x=a+\sqrt{ab}$.

Id est, 
$$OA+OB=b+\sqrt{ab}+a+\sqrt{ab}=(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2=1.$$

Comment: $m$ not suppose to be $\frac{-b}{a}$?

Comment: @xx01 No! $m=y'(a,b)$. See please better my post.

Comment: Thank you very much but I didn't understand the last step. can you explain me please?

Comment: @xx01 I added something. I hope now it's clear.

Comment: Yes I got it thank you very much!!! שבת שלום

Comment: @xx01 You are welcome! הצליח

Answer (score 2):

Hint

WLOG any point on the curve $P(\cos^4t,\sin^4t)$

So, the equation of the tangent at $P$ will be $$\dfrac{y-\sin^4t}{x-\cos^4t}=\dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}=\dfrac{4\sin^3t\cos t}{-4\cos^3t\sin t}$$

$$\dfrac y{\sin^2t}+\dfrac x{\cos^2t}=1$$

Can you calculate $OA,OB$ from here?

Comment: Answer  short and nice. I wonder what the general answer would be to the question: Find curve whose sum of  tangential intercepts on $x,y$ axes  is a constant.

Comment: @Narasimham, Thanks for the idea

Comment: I wonder what the parametrization of this curve would be in its full range. Thinking of  posing a question..